# what does each of the options under kernel tab in jupyter notebook mean?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to jupyter notebook and am trying to run python 2.7 on it. Can anyone help me to know or suggest me any link what kernel interrupt,kernel restart, kernel restart&clear output kernel& run do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Interrupt: sends the `SIGINT` signal to the kernel, which should raise a KeyboardInterrupt in your Python code. Use this if you want to stop running code.
- Restart: forcefully terminate the kernel process, and start a new one. Use this if your kernel is really stuck, or you just want to start fresh.
- Restart & Clear Output - this does the same thing as Restart, and then clears all the output from your notebook.
- Restart & Run All - this restarts the kernel and then executes your notebook in one go. This is often done when you are getting ready to finish working on a notebook, because it simulates opening the notebook and running it from scratch. It catches possible errors, such as missing imports, cells out of order, etc.